# $f(x) = x^2 + bx + a$ irreducible over $\Bbb F_p$ (finite field of $p$ prime elements) iff $(b^2 - 4a)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = -1$ in $\Bbb F_p$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

My attempt started as follows. I know that for $f$ to be irreducible, $D = b^2 - 4a$ is not a square in $\Bbb F_p$ (ie $(\frac{D}{p}) = -1$). I also know that $D^{p-1} = 1$, so I see $\sqrt{(D^{p-1})} = 1 \ or \ -1$. I am trying to now see if the fact that $D$ is not a square can give me the desired result $(b^2 - 4a)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = -1$.

One of my ideas was that $\sqrt{D} \ \in \ \Bbb F_{p^{2}}$. Call $\sqrt{D} = \alpha \in F_{p^{2}}$, then assume $\alpha^{p-1} - 1 = 0$.

I have no idea if this would lead to a contradiction or not (still trying to work it out). I would be super grateful for any comments on if I am heading in the wrong direction or what a next step could be.

Comment: First, you need $p \not= 2$. Granting that, show for nonzero $d$ in $\mathbf F_p$ that if $d$ is a square then $d^{(p-1)/2} = 1$ and if $d$ is not a square then $d^{(p-1)/2} = -1$. This is a standard theorem about squares and nonsquares mod $p$ and can be found in almost every number theory book. Look up Euler's congruence. There is no need to use $\mathbf F_{p^2}$.

Comment: I do recommend that you follow the route outlined by KCd. You can also try and combine the following. If $D=c^2$ for some $c\in\Bbb{F}_p$ then $D^{(p-1)/2}=c^{p-1}$. So for all squares $s$ you have $s^{(p-1)/2}=1$. But that equation can only have at most $(p-1)/2$ solutions, so...

Comment: I see it, that equation has all the squares as solutions, so the non-squares cannot be solutions to it.

Comment: Correct.  Well done, geo17! If you feel like it, you could try and type that as an answer. That way you will get more feedback. And this question gets removed from the unanswered queue. No pressure - your call!